# Drupal 7 - How to insert an image that is automatically resized and links to original in WYSIWYG?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor via the WYSIWYG module in Drupal 7, and I want to essentially be able to upload a photo that is automatically resized to a set size (ideally via an image style) and then is automatically linked back to the original?

I can accomplish this via other modules, but not in CKEditor and/or not in one click.

Comment: Do you use IMCE : https://www.drupal.org/project/imce ? It allows you to upload pictures on your server, resize it and use it within CKEditor. But you'll have to click a lot :) ...

Comment: @Flo Yes but I'm trying to make this significantly simpler. I just want to click a button, select the image and have it be inserted into the WYSIWYG with the image resized based on an image style and linked to the original (without doing all the clicking required with IMCE).

Comment: Did you try https://www.drupal.org/project/insert ? Bascially it allows you to insert a picture from an image field in a long text field (at the cursor position), using an image style. An "insert" button with an image style selector is added near the upload widget for the image style.